# TicTactoe Index Input

Tags: c++, arrays

Just want to ask about this code ad how it works. I just want to clarify some line of codes here.

I just basically want to display 'O' after every 'X' i place in the index on this basic tictactoe game. but when i do, i encounter some bugs like infinite loops that restricts the whole program to run. Please help me. Thank you.

Here's my function code.

```
int InputComHard() {
int num, ctr = 0,temp = 1;
if (field == 'X') {
cout << "Choose your field [Player X (1~9)]";

cin >> num;
} else {
cout << "Choose your field [Player O (1~9) ]";
for(int x = 0; x < 3;x++){
      for(int y = 0;y<3;y++){
              temp++;
              if(tic[x][y] =='X'&&tic[x][y+1]!='X'){

                           num = temp;
                           }
              }
      }

 }
  //Here's the condition where the 'X' or 'O' will be placed on the entire 
 matrix.
 if (num == 1 && tic[0][0] == NULL)
 tic[0][0] = field;
 else if (num == 2 && tic[0][1] == NULL)
 tic[0][1] = field;
 else if (num == 3 && tic[0][2] == NULL)
 tic[0][2] = field;
 else if (num == 4 && tic[1][0] == NULL)
 tic[1][0] = field;
 else if (num == 5 && tic[1][1] == NULL)
 tic[1][1] = field;
 else if (num == 6 && tic[1][2] == NULL)
 tic[1][2] = field;
 else if (num == 7 && tic[2][0] == NULL)
 tic[2][0] = field;
 else if (num == 8 && tic[2][1] == NULL)
 tic[2][1] = field;
 else if (num == 9 && tic[2][2] == NULL)
 tic[2][2] = field;
 else {
 ctr++;
 }
 return ctr;
 }
```

when i input 1, 'X' appears at index[0][0] and then, the 'O' appears at [0][1] SIMULTANEOUSLY, after that, when i enter 3, error begins, infinite loop occurs. What i just wanna basically do to my program is to display 'O' for every 'X' i enter and will be placed beside it. please help

```
    here is my main
    #include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
char tic[3][3];
char field = 'X';
void Draw() {
  //system("CLS");
  cout << "\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n";
  cout << "Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)" << endl << endl;
  cout << endl;
  //Displays the Matrix(rows and columns)
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << tic[0][0] << "  |  " << tic[0][1] << "  |  " << tic[0][2] << endl;
  cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << tic[1][0] << "  |  " << tic[1][1] << "  |  " << tic[1][2] << endl;
  cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
  cout << "  " << tic[2][0] << "  |  " << tic[2][1] << "  |  " << tic[2][2] << endl;
  cout << "     |     |     " << endl << endl;
  }
void Turn() {
  if (field == 'X')
     field = 'O';
  else
     field = 'X';
 }
  //Function to determine the winner based on the array positions.
char Winner() {

 int ctr = 0;

 if (tic[0][0] == 'X' && tic[0][1] == 'X' && tic[0][2] == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (tic[1][0] == 'X' && tic[1][1] == 'X' && tic[1][2] == 'X')
      return 'X';
  if (tic[2][0] == 'X' && tic[2][1] == 'X' && tic[2][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';

  if (tic[0][0] == 'X' && tic[1][0] == 'X' && tic[2][0] == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (tic[0][1] == 'X' && tic[1][1] == 'X' && tic[2][1] == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (tic[0][2] == 'X' && tic[1][2] == 'X' && tic[2][2] == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (tic[0][0] == 'X' && tic[1][1] == 'X' && tic[2][2] == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (tic[2][0] == 'X' && tic[1][1] == 'X' && tic[0][2] == 'X')
  return 'X';

  //second player
  if (tic[0][0] == 'O' && tic[0][1] == 'O' && tic[0][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (tic[1][0] == 'O' && tic[1][1] == 'O' && tic[1][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';
 if (tic[2][0] == 'O' && tic[2][1] == 'O' && tic[2][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';

  if (tic[0][0] == 'O' && tic[1][0] == 'O' && tic[2][0] == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (tic[0][1] == 'O' && tic[1][1] == 'O' && tic[2][1] == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (tic[0][2] == 'O' && tic[1][2] == 'O' && tic[2][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';

  if (tic[0][0] == 'O' && tic[1][1] == 'O' && tic[2][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (tic[2][0] == 'O' && tic[1][1] == 'O' && tic[0][2] == 'O')
  return 'O';
  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
     if (tic[x][y] == 'X' || tic[x][y] == 'O') {
        ctr++;
     }
    }
    if (ctr == 9) {
     return 'D';
   }
       }

}



    int main()

 {
  int choice;
  cout << "Choose Mode: \n";
  cout << "Player VS Player       [1]\n";
  cout << "Player VS BOT(EASY)    [2]\n";
  cout << "Player VS BOT(UNFAIR!) [3]\n";
  cin >> choice;
  switch (choice) {
  case 1:
     system("CLS");
     Draw();
     while (1) {
        if (Input() == 1) {
           system("CLS");
           cout << "Occupied!\n";
        } else {
           system("CLS");
           Turn();

        }
        Draw();
        if (Winner() == 'X') {
           cout << "X wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'O') {
           cout << "O wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'D') {
           cout << "DRAW!" << endl;
           break;
        }

     }
     break;

   case 2:
     system("CLS");
     Draw();
     while (1) {
        if (InputCom() == 1) {
           system("CLS");
           cout << "Occupied!\n";
        } else {
           system("CLS");
           Turn();

        }
        Draw();
        if (Winner() == 'X') {
           cout << "X wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'O') {
           cout << "O wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'D') {
           cout << "DRAW!" << endl;
           break;
        }

     }
     break;;
case 3:
     system("CLS");
     Draw();
     while (1) {
        if (InputComHard() == 1) {
           system("CLS");

           cout << "Occupied!\n";
        } else {
           system("CLS");
           Turn();

        }
        Draw();
        if (Winner() == 'X') {
           cout << "X wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'O') {
           cout << "O wins!" << endl;
           break;
        } else if (Winner() == 'D') {
           cout << "DRAW!" << endl;
           break;
        }

     }
     break;
  default:
     cout << "Invalid Input!" << endl;
  }

  system("pause");
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: Using `NULL` in `tic[0][0] == NULL` has the unfortunate side effect of fooling people into thinking `tic` is a 2D array of pointers when it isn't. using a nul character, '\0', or something like `const char blank = '\0'; better describes what you intend.

Comment: There's no obvious way for `InputComHard` itself to loop infinitely, so the difficulty probably lies in whatever is calling `InputComHard`.  Could you show us that code?

Comment: I already included my entire code. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to read the code, but I can see one fairly obvious problem that would cause infinite loops: when your bot takes a turn in `InputComHard()`, it chooses the same (occupied) square every time. When you call it from `main()`, you get a `1` back from it, indicating an occupied square, but then you just call it again. You need some way to tell it to choose some square that it has not already attempted.

Or better yet, change `InputComHard()` such that it doesn't return until it has successfully chosen an available square.

Also, in `InputComHard()`, you're declaring `num` without initializing it. When your bot takes a turn, if you never satisfy the condition `if(tic[x][y] =='X'&&tic[x][y+1]!='X')`, then you'll never reach the `num = temp`, and `num` will end up with a garbage value in it. This will likely cause you some kind of trouble, perhaps looping, perhaps other stuff even worse.